# Margin not working on bootstrap form items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My form:

[image: My form]

I'm trying to align the buttons/input areas in my form. I've tried adding bootstrap margin options to their classes to move them to no available, for example adding ml-n2 to the date input to move it closer to the label "Date and Time". I've tried many variations of CSS/bootstrap to change the margins and I don't understand why the buttons/inputs aren't moving. How can I align the left side of the "Non-smoking" button, "Date" input, and "Cancel" button? I've linked a picture of my form above.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label name="section" class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-form-label">Section</label>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-success btn-sm text-white"><input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" class="active">Non-Smoking</label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-white"><input type="radio" name="options" id="options2" autocomplete="off">Smoking</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label name="datetime" class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-form-label">Date and Time</label>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 mt-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" value="Date">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 mt-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time" id="time" placeholder="Time">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="offset-md-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary text-white">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="ml-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-white">Reserve</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

col class and btn-group class have some default padding values so try changing that. Set padding-left value to 0%.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label name="section" class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-form-label">Section</label>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="buttons"style="padding-left:0% !important" >
    <label class="btn btn-success btn-sm text-white"><input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" class="active">Non-Smoking</label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-white"><input type="radio" name="options" id="options2" autocomplete="off">Smoking</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label name="datetime" class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-form-label">Date and Time</label>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 mt-3" style="padding-left:0% !important">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" value="Date">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 mt-3" style="padding-left:0% !important">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time" id="time" placeholder="Time">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="offset-md-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary text-white">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="ml-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-white">Reserve</button>
  </div>
</div>
```